# How do I change Show Workspace Selector hot key in Workspace Matrix on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, workspace-switcher

I'm using the Gnome Shell extension [Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) in Ubuntu 18 and would like to change the hot key for it (it's currently <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) but haven't been able to find where that's set.

Using *dconf Editor*, I'm not seeing any option for it under `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings` or under `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/wsmatrix`.

How is this done?

Comment: Is this a standard Ubuntu desktop with Gnome Shell, or is this about a specific application? In the latter case, provide more information on the application.

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/issues/83

Comment: @vanadium, this is standard Ubuntu with Gnome Shell. I've added a link to Workspace Matrix.

Comment: Look for the option to change the hotkey under the gsettings of the extension itself. If not there, and not configurable in the extension's options, it will probably be hardcoded in the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/issues/47:

```
$ sudo cp ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.wsmatrix.gschema.xml  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
$ sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Then use `gsettings` or `dconf` to set `org.gnome.shell.extensions.wsmatrix-keybindings` `workspace-overview-toggle`.